# Angular , Can't access Authorization from response header

Tags: angular, http, header, response

[image][image]I am calling login api and api is sending Authorization Token in the response header, i can see Authorization and token from chrome dev tools networks , but in login service, i cannot see Authorization data in response.header.

Login

```
 return this.http.post('http://login_url', formData, options )
        .subscribe((response : Response ) => {

         let userJson = response.headers;
         console.log("Data",userJson);

        },
        error => console.log(error)
       );[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Comment: Why not set authorization token to response body instead of response header?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use ***authorization headers***

```
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9...
```

you should also add to server response ***expose headers***, to make it available for browser

```
access-control-expose-headers: Authorization,authorization
```